# Overriding Jquery alert for application

Tags: jquery

How to override alert in jquery perfectly.In my application width is not auto adjust with the alert message.
           The main problem I am getting after  overriding my alert message is not staying on the screen.when ever i am submitting the page

### $.extend({ alert: function (message, title) { $("").dialog( { buttons: { "OK": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }, close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); }, re sizable: false, title: title, modal: true }).text(message); } });

Comment: Why try to override the alert function?  Just create a dialog model that has the info you need to display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that may help get you "kick started" for a custom error message.  A working example is here on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vh0kr4ww/).

HTML

```
 <div id="errorMsg"></div>
```

jQuery

```
function displayError(errTitle, errMsg) {
var modalWait = $("#errorMsg").dialog({
    title: errTitle,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        OK: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open: function () {
        $("#errorMsg").html(errMsg);
        $(".ui-dialog").css("text-align", "center").css("float", "none");
        $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").css("text-align", "center").css("float", "none");
        $(".ui-dialog-buttonset").css("float", "none");

    },
    close: function () {
        $("#errorMsg").html("");
    }



});

}
```